# Why this re.search not working

Tags: python, regex

Why re.search can't find the pattern?

```
str = "<a href='http://'>\ntest\n'</a>"
re.search(r"<a[^>]+>.", str, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Did you try `re.search(r"<a[^>]+>", str, re.MULTILINE)`?

Comment: You should't use `str` as a variable name, as it's also a builtin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` won't match a newline unless you use `re.DOTALL`

```
mystr = "<a href='http://'>\ntest\n'</a>"
re.search(r"<a[^>]+>.", mystr, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```